# GPS map in java

Tags: java, google-maps

I want to write a client - Server navigation app in Java, the client only sends its position to the server, the server is building a map with the client position and any route. How can I create a map in java ? maybe there is a way to use Google Maps ?

Comment: check out the unfoldingMaps API for java [Link](http://unfoldingmaps.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the server side:**

Google has a [Java Google Maps Web Services](https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/client-library) you can use. This enables you to work with Google Maps web services on your server.

**For the client side:**

To make a Java google maps program, try to delve into JavaFX, thanks to Java 1.8. It has WebEngine and WebView classes which you can use to load the google maps URL.

Here's a snippet:

```
@Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        // create web engine and view
        final WebEngine webEngine = new WebEngine(getClass().getResource("googlemap.html").toString());
        final WebView webView = new WebView(webEngine);
        // create scene
        stage.setTitle("Web Map");
        Scene scene = new Scene(webView,1000,700, Color.web("#666970"));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        // show stage
        stage.setVisible(true);
 }
```

Here's a link to the [full tutorial](http://fxexperience.com/2011/05/maps-in-javafx-2-0/).

If you want you can also explore into [GMapsFX](http://rterp.github.io/GMapsFX/),a wrapper to the Google Map's Javascript API, allowing you to use and interact with maps using a pure Java API.